# Accessing a linux machine with a name (not ip address)

Tags: ssh, networking, ip

When I access a linux machine with sshfs, I take the following steps.

1. Get the ip address of the linux (the ip address is dynamically allocated to linux)
2. Run sshfs id@ip_address:/HOME_DIRECTORY

Can I use a name, not ip address to access the linux machine?

### ADDED

To me, avahi seems to be the best solution as it enables Mac understands the name without any configuration. With ubuntu, I could install avahi as follows :

```
sudo apt-get install avahi-daemon
```

Comment: set your dhcp server to offer the same ip to your linux machine and add an entry to your hosts file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the machines are on the same network, you should be able to just use the machine's host name instead of its IP address.

Comment: With avahi, I could use "host name".local to be accessed both Mac and PC (bonjour for PC installed).

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the resolution from a network name to an ip address, which is exactly what DNS is for.

If the linux machine is on your LAN, IMHO [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) would fit best.

> Dnsmasq is a lightweight, easy to
>   configure DNS forwarder and DHCP
>   server. It is designed to provide DNS
>   and, optionally, DHCP, to a small
>   network. It can serve the names of
>   local machines which are not in the
>   global DNS. The DHCP server integrates
>   with the DNS server and allows
>   machines with DHCP-allocated addresses
>   to appear in the DNS with names
>   configured either in each host or in a
>   central configuration file. Dnsmasq
>   supports static and dynamic DHCP
>   leases and BOOTP/TFTP/PXE for network
>   booting of diskless machines.

If its on the internet, you could use some dynamic dns provider. A popular free provider is [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/).

Comment: Additionally, if you have a constant but ugly name for your machine such as `prosseek-home.dyndns.org`, you can give it a nickname in ssh with a `Host home` ␤ `HostName prosseek-home.dyndns.org` ␤ section in `~/.ssh/config`.

Answer (score 2):

There are several possibilities.

1. choose a dyndns service (not suitable for local IP address)
2. configure the machine in `/etc/hosts` (only for static IP address)
3. run your own DNS server (optimal for LAN)